# If you can use things other than real numbers with Cayley-Dickson construction, or something related to it.

Tags: complex-numbers

Wondering if there are constructions related to the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) in which it is built not out of real numbers but of arbitrary abstract objects. Similar to how you can have [polynomial rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) that aren't of the real numbers, or algebras over things other than real numbers. Basically, if you can use the Cayley-Dickson construction without real-numbers, with, say, vectors of arbitrary dimension. So it would go:

- 1-dimension: 3-variable vector instead of real number.
- 2-dimension: 2 3-variable vectors instead of complex number.
- etc.

Comment: As far as I know, the Cayley-Dickson construction only depends on a ring having an an involution which is also an antihomomorphism.  If you want to use the construction with "arbitrary vectors of real numbers" then you'd have to decide on what the product and involutions are (presumably you've already decided that the addition is vector addition.)